# Open ResponseEntity PDF in new browser tab

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pdf

I came across a helpful PDF generation code to show the file to the client in a Spring MVC application (["*Return generated PDF using Spring MVC*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16656382/3287503)):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form/pdf", produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> showPdf(DomainModel domain, ModelMap model) {
    createPdf(domain, model);

    Path path = Paths.get(PATH_FILE);
    byte[] pdfContents = null;
    try {
        pdfContents = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    String filename = NAME_PDF;
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(
            pdfContents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

I added a declaration that the method returns a PDF file (["*Spring 3.0 Java REST return PDF document*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11804233/3287503)): `produces = "application/pdf"`.

My problem is that when the code above is executed, it immediately asks the client to save the PDF file. I want the PDF file to be viewed first in the browser so that the client can decide whether to save it or not.

I found ["*How to get PDF content (served from a Spring MVC controller method) to appear in a new window*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9401602/3287503) that suggests to add `target="_blank"` in the Spring form tag. I tested it and as expected, it showed a new tab but the save prompt appeared again.

Another is ["*I can't open a .pdf in my browser by Java*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5040830/3287503)'s method to add `httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "inline");` but I don't use `HttpServletRequest` to serve my PDF file.

How can I open the PDF file in a new tab given my code/situation?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
```

But using the responseEntity as follows.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(
            pdfContents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

It should work

Not sure about this, but it seems you are using bad the setContentDispositionFormData, try>

```
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName);
```

Let me know if that works

**UPDATE**

> This behavior depends on the browser and the file you are trying to
>   serve. With inline, the browser will try to open the file within the
>   browser.

```
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", fileName);
```

Or

```
headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName)
```

Read this to know difference [between inline and attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)

Comment: Hello! I added `headers.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)` and it still asks for the PDF to be saved :( It didn't show the PDF file in a new browser tab (thank you for the edit, yes, I missed that one)

Comment: I added an update in my answer, try a shoot using inline insead of attachment

Comment: `headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName);` did the trick (without the other one). Thank you!

Comment: response.setHeader("Content-Disposition:inline", "attachment; filename="+filename); worked for IE

Comment: But how do you "encode" the `fileName` in `headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName)`? Because a `fileName` of `"x.txt"; attachment; filename*=UTF-8''trick.exe` will mess up with client's interpretation of HTTP headers

Comment: I think you could try URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8")

Comment: @Koitoer Your answer is working fine ! But I want to stay existing tab when pdf is opening in new tab. Is there any way ??

Comment: you guys have UI ? i tried xmlhttprequest to fetch blob then download but it fails. Even with inline!

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot 2

Use this code to display the pdf in the browser.
(PDF in directory resources -> CLASSPATH)
Using ResponseEntity<?>

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/showPDF")
public ResponseEntity<?> exportarPDF( ){        
    
    InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(service.exportPDF());
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline;attachment; filename=ayuda.pdf")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(file);            
}




@Service
public class AyudaServiceImpl implements AyudaService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadPDF.class);
    
    LoadPDF  pdf = new LoadPDF();
    
    public InputStream exportPDF() {    
        LOGGER.info("Inicia metodo de negocio :: getPDF");                  
        return pdf.getPDF();
    }
}
```

---CLASE

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;


public class LoadPDF {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadPDF.class);
    public  InputStream getPDF(){        
               
        try {
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:ayuda.pdf");
            LOGGER.debug("Ruta del archivo pdf: [" + file + "]");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            LOGGER.info("Encontro el archivo PDF");
            return in;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("No encontro el archivo PDF",e.getMessage());
            throw new AyudaException("No encontro el archivo PDF", e ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Here is a simple code that worked just fine to open pdf(byte stream) file 
* in browser , Assuming you have a a method yourService.getPdfContent() that 
* returns the bite stream for the pdf file
*/

@GET
@Path("/download/")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public byte[] getDownload() {
   byte[] pdfContents = yourService.getPdfContent();
   return pdfContents;
}
```

Comment: is this Spring Boot?

Comment: @Produces("application/pdf") does not seem to be spring boot

Comment: sorry i may have confused that with some other spring-boot project i had. The Produces("application/pdf") as described here is JAX-RS , https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-pdf-file-from-jax-rs/

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that since you "manually" provided headers to the response, Spring did not added the other headers (e.g. produces="application/pdf"). Here's the minimum code to display the pdf inline in the browser using Spring:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/form/pdf", produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> showPdf() {
    // getPdfBytes() simply returns: byte[]
    return ResponseEntity.ok(getPdfBytes());
}
```